# what are the steps to work on real time project with home care agency data..like implementing Databases and BI Solution and then Reporting?

Tags: sql-server, modeling, msbi

I am a graduate having some practical experience(beginner level) on MS-BI/Data Modelling.want to work on a project to gain experience and able to apply for full-time jobs.I have real data of my brother's Home Care agency to work on....All the data is in excel/paper folders/files...So my question is where to start?Should i start from implementing relational databases for ERP System and data-warehouse first and then through (SSIS,SSAS,SSRS) and finally reporting on excel?please advice!(Note:I do have resources provided-PC,Server(SQL Server 2008 R2),MSBI-BIDS(Developer Edition)...

Comment: As a graduate, you should be able to find full-time positions, it just takes a little effort and time. If you truly can't find anything, apply for internships or part-time/substitutional jobs to give you the desired experience. It is difficult to give any concise advice on such a broad topic. The tech industry is huge, and people are in demand as of right now. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start to implement a normalised database in Microsoft Access for your brother. You can do this parallel to his excel/paper/folders and files. If your database model is finished and it works, you can upsize it to SQL Sever and start building reports with SSRS. This way you have covered a lot of steps which might come to you in your new job. Good luck btw :-)